# Can not save sources.list

Tags: source.list

I have been having trouble using `sudo apt-get update`, howevr this is a separate problem. In trying to fix this problem by adding a different mirror in `/etc/apt/sources.list/` I am having trouble. Whenever I open `sources.list` with the default RPi text editor and then try to save it after editing, I get this error:

> Can't open file to write.

I have been trying but can not figure out why this happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sources.list` file is owned by root, which means that the standard Raspberry Pi user doesn't have write access to the file. The simplest way to get a graphical, root level file editor is by opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo leafpad
```

Then, use the open dialog to select `/etc/apt/sources.list/`. You should now be able to make changes and save the file. Simply close leafpad when you're done and you should see a new prompt appear in the terminal window once the leafpad process exits. You can now close the terminal window as well.